# How do I remove each list item one after another with a 10 second delay with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Im trying to remove items in a list one by one but cant seem to get this to work. I need them removed individually and one after another- not all at the same time. I need them removed with a delay in between each removal, preferably 10 seconds. Can anyone help?

```
 <div class="health-bar">
   <ul>
    <li class="heart5"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart4"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart3"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart2"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart1"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face"  width="60px"> </li>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

> I got this far but stopped because I know this isn't correct.

```
 $('.health-bar ul li.heart5').delay(10000).remove();
 $('.health-bar ul li.heart4').delay(20000).remove();
 $('.health-bar ul li.heart3').delay(30000).remove();
 $('.health-bar ul li.heart2').delay(40000).remove();
 $('.health-bar ul li.heart1').delay(50000).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using a setTimeout. Because `.delay()` is a function belongs to animation queue.

```
var lis = $(".health-bar > ul > li");
for(var i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
 (function(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   lis.eq(i).remove();
  }, (i+1) * 10000);
 })(i);
}
```

And if you prefer to use ES6, then things becomes even more simpler.

```
let lis = $(".health-bar > ul > li");
for(let i=0; i<lis.length; i++){
  setTimeout(function(){
   lis.eq(i).remove();
  }, (i+1) * 10000);
}
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s735r941/)

Comment: var lis = $(".health-bar ul li");
for(var i=1; i<=lis.length; i++){
 (function(i) {
  setTimeout(function(){
   lis.eq(i).remove();
  }, i * 10000);
 })(i);
}

Comment: The above totally worked. Just had to make some minor changes. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yeah I just fixed and updated the answer. Your code has a little problem too. `lis.eq(i).remove();` This line will always ignore the first element. Use the updated code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the loop which might be a little cleaner. This example has a timeout of a second, so adjust that to your requirements.

```js
let items = $('.health-bar ul li');

setTimeout(checkItems, 1000, items, 0);

function checkItems(items, index) {
  if (index < items.length) {
    items.eq(index).remove();
    setTimeout(checkItems, 1000, items, ++index);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="health-bar">
  <ul>
    <li class="heart5"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face" width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart4"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face" width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart3"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face" width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart2"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face" width="60px"> </li>
    <li class="heart1"><img src="heart.png" alt="Smiley face" width="60px"> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```